# PHP PDO SQL Query alias UTF-8

Tags: php, pdo, adodb, sqlsrv

I'm trying to get alias table as UTF-8, in a simple select query, but i get gibberish in the alias column name.

Here is my code:

```
include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php"); 
//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn =&ADONewConnection ('sqlsrv');
//define connection string, specify database driver
$conn->Connect('xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1400', 'user', 'password', 'DbName');
//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "select firstName as 'שם פרטי' from users";
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
//execute the SQL statement and return records
$arr = $rs->GetArray();
print_r($arr);
```

And this is my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [�� ����] =&gt; יעקב
            [0] =&gt; יעקב
        )
)
```

The results r UTF-8, but i cant get the alias of the column in UTF-8.

any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the UTF-8 decoding in the connection string like:

```
$dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname . ';charset=UTF8', 
$username, $password);
```

Comment: you try with mysql and not with sqlsrv like i ask :) and for me this is good for the result, and not helping for the alias it self